# Button with rx.tap subscription reaching completed

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm a newbie to RxSwift and I'm trying to implement login facebook feature, and here's what I'm doing:

```
loginButton.rx.tap
            .debug("login tapped")
            .flatMap { [weak self] ()->Observable<AccessToken> in
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    throw NetworkError.requestCancelled
                }
                return strongSelf.viewModel.loginFacebook(from: strongSelf)
            }
            .flatMap { [weak self] accessToken->Observable<(accessToken: String, userId: String)> in
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    throw NetworkError.requestCancelled
                }
                return strongSelf.viewModel.requestUserInfo(token: accessToken)
            }
            .flatMap { [weak self] (accessToken: String, userId: String)->Observable<LoginResult> in
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    throw NetworkError.requestCancelled
                }
                return strongSelf.viewModel.authenticate(accessToken: accessToken, userId: userId)
            }
            .catchError({ error -> Observable<LoginResult> in
                return Observable.just(LoginResult.failure(error: error as! NetworkError))
            })
            .subscribe (onNext:{ [weak self] result in
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    return
                }

                switch result {
                case .success:
                    // do something with success
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    // do something with error
                }
            }, onCompleted: {
                print("rx.tap completed")
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The thing is when I tap login button then close the login window of Facebook that pops up, my subscription to `rx.tap`reaches `onCompleted`, so then when I try to tap the button again, nothing happens. How should I handle this case? Any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a simplified scheme of your chain:

```
loginButton.rx.tap
    .flatMap({ (_) -> Observable<Void> in
        throw NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [:])
    })
    .catchError({ error -> Observable<Void> in
        return Observable<Void>.just()
    })
    .subscribe()
```

When you produce `Observable<Void>.just()` in `catchError` block or something similar in other blocks, it will fire only once and that is why you receive `completed` and nothing else happens later. I advice to put all the code you have into `flatMapLatest` for example. The result code will be:

```
loginButton.rx.tap
    .flatMapLatest({ _ -> Observable<Void> in
        return Observable<Void>
            .just()
            .flatMap({ (_) -> Observable<Void> in
                throw NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [:])
            })
            .catchError({ error -> Observable<Void> in
                return Observable<Void>.just()
            })
    })
    .subscribe()
```

Hope it helps

P.S. Check the [similar answer](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/304#issuecomment-161217976) from the RxSwift development team member